# NetBeams onActionPerformed(...) Int parameter not working?

Tags: java, variables, methods, init

As a newcomer its pretty hard to figure out all the details,
especially when you get an error like this:

What i got in following main class:

INIT-part:

```
jButtonStart.setText("START");
jButtonStart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        jButtonStartActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

and my `jButtonStartActionPerformed` method:

```
public void jButtonStartActionPerformed(int var1, java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    // HANDLING CODE SHORTENED...
    String result = var1 + "";
    jTextField1.setText(result);
}
```

Now this actually doesn't work for any reason...
In the init part (at `jButtonStartActionPerformed(evt);`) it complains about my `int var1` parameter which are set in `jButtonStartActionPerformed(int var1, java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)`.

Error message:

```
method can not be applied
required: int, ActionEvent
found: ActionEvent
```

Comment: i couldnt fix it so far :/

Comment: Your method requires two arguments.  When you call it, you're only providing one.

Comment: `jButtonStartActionPerformed(evt);` would need to become `jButtonStartActionPerformed(1, evt);` or something equivalent. Having said that, you shouldn't really do this.  Instead, you should use the `ActionEvent` and associated information to make decisions about what you should do

Comment: thanks, and sorry for asking again :)
it did of course work with "1,evt" but when i changed it to a variable:
'jButtonStart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt, int var1) {
                jButtonStartActionPerformed(var1, evt);'

it says that jButtonStart.add[...] is not abstract... what is my mistake?
         

thanks again.